# C++ the operator ## don't work with a string and a macro

Tags: c++, macros, c-preprocessor

The ## are not working with an string an a macro. My compiler not extract the value of the macro or something else after ##

`#define ProfilerScope(name) Timer timer ## __LINE__;`

This just returns me `Timer timer__LINE__`

I tried to make a STRINGIZE macro to makes this works but nothing, they just returns me the same

```cpp
#define STRINGIZE(x) STRINGIZE_SIMPLE(x)
#define STRINGIZE_SIMPLE(x) #x

#define ProfilerScope(name) Timer timer ## STRINGIZE(__LINE__);
```

return `Timer timerSTRINGIZE(__LINE__)`

I want it to return the line of code where I'm using the macro

Comment: `STRINGIZE` adds quotes, and `Timer timer42;` is supposed to have no quotes. But notice how `STRINGIZE` uses two macros instead of one. You must do the same: pass `__LINE__` from one macro to another, then use `##` in the second macro.

Comment: `##` operator applies after parameter substitution but before the list is reprocessed for further macro replacements. You need a couple levels of indirection, with `##` at the very end. [Something like this](https://godbolt.org/z/9hqcbM1cf)

Comment: `This just returns me Timer timer__LINE__` How do you know?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I want it to return the line of code where I'm using the macro

I think you want to expand `__LINE__` and *then* concatenate it with a word. You have to expand it in a macro. The following code:

```
#define CONCAT(a, b)  CONCAT2(a, b)
#define CONCAT2(a, b)  a##b
#define ProfilerScope(name) Timer CONCAT(timer, __LINE__);
ProfilerScope()
```

outputs `Timer timer4;`.